# Excel VBA - stored value changes format when entered into a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table I need to fill with some information for each client job according to the client job ID, and I pull the info using vlookup within VBA.

```
Dim jobID as double, path as String, creationDate as date
For i = 2 to 100
    jobID = Sheet11.Cells(i, 1).Value
    path = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobID, Sheet9.Range("A:G"), 7, False)
    creationDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobID, Sheet9.Range("A:M"), 13, False)
    Sheet11.Cells(i, 6).Value = creationDate
    Sheet11.Cells(i, 8).Value = path
Next i
```

The paths in sheet 9 look like "180,28,60,91,40,178" or "179,143,141,142,178" and has "General" format. The creation dates in sheet 9 look like "2015-11-12 11:44" and has yyyy-mm-dd h:mm custom date format. However, when the stored values were entered into sheet11 as shown, some of the paths were converted to numbers e.g. "179,143,141,142,178" became "179143141142178", although some stayed as string as I intended e.g. "180,28,60,91,40,178". Most dates also lost time information (h:mm info) and was entered in sheet11 in yyyy-mm-dd format, while some maintained original format.

Could someone help me maintain all the information from the date  and prevent the path stored as string to become a number?

Comment: You need to set the NumberFormat of the destination cells before copying over the values.

Answer (score 2):

Excel is trying its best to repair what it thinks are errors in your data.

A standard *thousands separator* puts a comma every third digit. This is a standard method of expressing numbers. `179,143,141,142,178` can be viewed as a real number.

When Excel sees a value like `180,28,60,91,40,178` it doesn't know what to do with it as the two digits separated by commas are not a standard method of expressing numerical values so it treats them as text.

If you have not manually changed the cell alignment, widen the column and look at the values. Text values by default are left aligned in a cell; numerical values and dates (which are considered numerical) are right aligned by default in a cell. This will quickly show you what Excel 'thinks' is a number and what it 'thinks' is text.

Format the target path as Text, not General. Format the target date to include a time value.

```
Dim jobID as double, path as String, creationDate as date
For i = 2 to 100
    jobID = Sheet11.Cells(i, 1).Value
    path = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobID, Sheet9.Range("A:G"), 7, False)
    creationDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobID, Sheet9.Range("A:M"), 13, False)
    Sheet11.Cells(i, 6).NUMBERFORMAT = "yyyy-mm-dd h:mm"
    Sheet11.Cells(i, 6).Value = creationDate
    Sheet11.Cells(i, 8).NUMBERFORMAT = "@"
    Sheet11.Cells(i, 8).Value = path
Next i
```

**Addendum:**

It has occurred to me that your source values may be a mash-up[ of text and numbers. Locating the source row and using that to pull the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) may be a better fit.

```
Dim jobID as double, path as String, creationDate as date, rw as variant
For i = 2 to 100
    jobID = Sheet11.Cells(i, 1).Value
    rw = Application.Match(jobID, Sheet9.Columns("A"), 0)
    if not iserror(rw) then 
        path = Sheet9.Cells(rw, "G").TEXT  'this will return whatever is displayed; not the underlying value
        creationDate = Sheet9.Cells(rw, "M").VALUE2
        Sheet11.Cells(i, 6).NUMBERFORMAT = "yyyy-mm-dd h:mm"
        Sheet11.Cells(i, 6).Value = creationDate
        Sheet11.Cells(i, 8).NUMBERFORMAT = "@"
        Sheet11.Cells(i, 8).Value = path
    end if
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to format the cells then here is the simplest way to do it

```
Sheet11.Cells(i, 8).Value = "'" & path
```

Comment: I prefer `Chr(39)` but `'` will do.

Comment: Chr(39) is 7 characters. "'" is 3 :D

Comment: ... and `vbNullString` is twelve characters while `""` is two but `vbNullString` executes faster.

Comment: True that! However `Chr(39)` and `"'"` are almost same. Performance wise `"'"` is faster than `Chr(39)` because excel has to convert `Chr(39)` to `'` but then the difference is insignificantly small. In such a scenario, the shorter string takes precedence :)

Comment: ... unless you prefer to exercise the ASCII table (and possibly a little hubris) you have memorized.

Comment: lol.. true. I love using ASCII for cases like `"` where I use Chr(34). `& Chr(34) &` is more "cleaner" than `""""` in IMHO. :D

Comment: ... maybe `Chr(34)` ...? And `TEXT(,)` is my new preferred method of expressing `""""` in a string representing a formula.