# Change Date To String with format "mmm-yy"

Tags: excel, vba, string, date, unique

I have a column of dates. I want to modify the format and convert to text.

I'm doing this because I have dates with various days, but need to only find the unique month-year combos. When I format the dates to show "mmm-yy" and then try to get the unique values it still sees the day values and provides more unique values than I need.

To resolve this, I'm trying to remove the "value" of the dates and convert to a string which I can then remove the days.

Dates I'm trying to convert are showing in the sheet as 31-DEC-22 (for example) and all show a warning "This cell contains a date string represented with only two digits for the year." I don't care about the year digits, but unsure if this warning is part of the problem.

I tried to convert to a string:

`dateValue = CStr(dateValue)`

`Column.NumberFormat = "General"`

`str = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(dateValue, "MMM-YY")`

`Dim str As String = Format(dateValue, "MMM-YY")`

With all of the above when I add the resulting values to a cell, it shows as properly formatted, but when viewing the value still shows the full date with day and show as Custom Format.

FYI the only way I get this to work, is by adding a single quote to each value.

Comment: `str = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(dateValue, "MMM-YY")` is fine.  But assigning it to variable str does not get it back into the worksheet. You need to do something like Range("A1")=Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(dateValue, "MMM-YY") to replace the result into the sheet.

Comment: Hi Chris, Yes. I should have been clearer above. For all example solutions above I took the resulting values and added them to a cell. As example mySheet.Cells(1,1).Value = str. However that cell showed formatted like Dec-22, but the value was still 12/31/22.

Comment: _need to only find the unique month-year combos_ What are you doing with these values ? You need to change the cell format first `Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "@"` and then `.Value = str`

Comment: The assignment to a cell is triggering all kinds of *interpretive* logic on the part of EXCEL.  TLDR: @CDP1802 is right, but check out this other S.O. answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39652915/5440883

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to find unique Month/Year values, why not loop over your data and build a dictionary holding the MMM-YY values?

Comment: Thank you Chris and CDP. Your comments helped me understand why all of my attempts to convert to text keep resulting in the values being converted back into a date.

Comment: @FunThomas I am using a Collection and assigning the values to the keys to get unique values, however each time I passed a date formatted as "MMM-YY" the date value passed  still contained the day values so 31-12-22 and 29-12-22, were coming out as two unique values, when I really wanted only one DEC-22 value to come out.

Comment: I understand that, but instead of writing the MMM-YY first back to the sheet, you could simply use Format(dateValue, "MMM-YY") directly as key into your collection (or dictionary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel will convert any string containing a valid date into a date unless, explicitly tell excel that is not a date like by adding a single quote

```
mySheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "'" & str
```

or by changing the format to text before assigning the value

```
mySheet.Cells(1,1).NumberFormat = "@"
mySheet.Cells(1,1).Value = str
```